# How to repeat VBA macro with cell references changing

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have written the following code which scrapes webpages based on a URL (in cell B2) and then outputs a number scraped from the page in C2.

```
Sub Scrape()
    Dim ObjIE As Object
    Set ObjIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ObjIE.Navigate Sheets("facebook").Range("B2").Value

    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

    Do While ObjIE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."

    Dim dd As String
    dd = ObjIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("_3xom")(0).innerText

    Sheets("Facebook").Range("C2") = dd

    Dim cell As Range
End Sub
```

I have more URLs in column B. I need to find some code which will repeat the macro but change the two cell references to "B3" and "C3" respectively, and then 4, 5, 6 and so forth. I've tried all kind of loops but cant work out what might make this work!

Any help would be super appreciated.

Comment: Look at using `.Cells` instead of `.Range.`  With that type of cell reference you can set up a loop such as `Dim i As Long; For i = 1 To 10; ObjIE.Navigate Sheets("facebook").Cells(i,2).Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
Sub Scrape()
    Dim ObjIE As Object
    Dim record As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("facebook")
    For Each record In Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 2))

        Set ObjIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        ObjIE.Navigate record.Value

        Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

        Do While ObjIE.Busy
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop


        Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."

        Dim dd As String
        dd = ObjIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("_3xom")(0).innerText
        record.Offset(0, 1).Value = dd
    Next record
End Sub
```

We iterate over all your cells, in column 2 ("B"), and then we do your "scraping" and place the value in the next column, which is 3 ("C").

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
Sub Scrape()
Dim cell As Range
Dim dd As String
Dim ObjIE As Object
Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Facebook")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 2 To LastRow

    Set ObjIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ObjIE.Navigate ws.Cells(i, 2).Value 'this refers to row i in column 2 (ie. B)

    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

    Do While ObjIE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."

    dd = ObjIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("_3xom")(0).innerText

    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = dd 'this refers to row i in column 3 (ie. C)
Next i
End Sub
```